# Turn a mac mini g4 - 1.4 ghz, 2 gb ram - into a home server

Tags: server, performance, mac-mini

I'd like to build a small home server (backups, download station and media server with dlna).
Anybody knows if this spare mac I have is worth for the specified jobs using Ubuntu Server (I've already found the working iso) or it's just a waste of time keeping in mind that I'd need to stream using dlna 1080p movies?
I can't predict its performance because of my poor experience on risc processors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience doing exactly what you want to do, but as an "old mac guy", I have a lot of experience w/ G4 processors, and a 1.4GHz G4 would be roughly equivalent to a 2.4GHz Pentium 4 which according to the [Passmark site listing all benchmarked CPU's](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_list.php) earns a Passmark score of 314, which to put in perspective would be roughly in line with a 1st Gen Atom from the first Netbooks that started floating around.